# Property 'id' does not exist on type '' В аргументе функции

Tags: vue.js, typescript, typescript-типы

Я написал dispatch который авторизует пользователя и в случае успеха возвращает тип User или ResponseError

Собственно сам dispatch

```
export interface User {
  id?: number
}

export interface ErrorResponse {
  status: number
  errors: object
}

export interface Actions {
  loginUser({ commit }: { commit: Commit }, data: LoginData): Promise<User | ErrorResponse>
}

async loginUser ({ commit }, data) {
    try {
      const user = await loginUser(data)
      commit('setUser', user)
      return user
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        status: e.response.status,
        errors: e.response.data.errors
      }
    }
  }
```

Вызываю мой dispatch в компоненте

```
const res = await this.$store.dispatch('loginUser', {
   email: this.formData.email,
   password: this.formData.password
})

redirect(res, 'dashboard')
```

И в ф-ции redirect я либо делаю редирект на какую то страницу или в случае ошибки показываю предупреждение

```
const redirect = (res: User | ErrorResponse, redirectTo: string) => {
  if (res.id) {
    router.push({ name: redirectTo })
  } else {
    ElMessage.error('Oops, this is a error message.')
  }
}
```

Но TS показывает мне ошибку  `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User | ErrorResponse'.Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ErrorResponse'.`

Что мне нужно сделать, что бы TS не выкидывало в данном случае ошибку?

Comment: @yar85, а что, `instanceof` начал с `interface` работать? :)

Comment: @Grundy, ой, точно... не начал, и не начнет (интерфейс не рантайм-сущность). Видимо, тут только тайпгард и остается, если классом не реализовывать.

Comment: Самый оптимальный способ решить данную проблему, это использовать Type Predicate: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates